# How to use Linux DHCP server to issue static addresses to VPN Pool?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, cisco, linux-networking

I am having trouble figuring out this setup. I need 4-8 clients to connect to my location via a VPN using a Cisco RV345.I will also use a Linux DHCP server for issuing IP addresses. The reason I have chose to use Linux as the DHCP server rather than just using the RV345 server, is because I need to be able to issue static addresses. I cannot find an option to do this with any of the VPNs on the RV345.

Basically, my question is, how would I set this up on the RV345 and which VPN type would be best for what I'm trying to do? Would I tell the RV345 to use the Linux DHCP server as a DHCP relay?

Also, if anyone is aware of how I can issue static IPs from the pool on the RV345 instead so I can just eliminate the Linux server altogether, that would be even better. Please let me know. All help is appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: It looks like the RV345 supports static dhcp. See page 62 of https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/RV345/Administration_Guide/EN/b_RV345_RV345P_EN_AG.pdf

Comment: @MarkWagner I believe that does not apply to the VPN pool, just the LAN. If I'm wrong (which I very well may be) please let me know.

Comment: @MarkWagner Scratch that, just tested it out. No luck. Doesn't apply to the VPN.